# Logging in with cURL into API without form

Tags: api, curl, authentication, request

I'm creating an API which obviously needs to be accessed through someones client and not a form. But I want to tryout this for myself and don't know how I would go about doing this.

I basically have a page that I only want to show if you're authorised.

Since i'm not too familiar with cURL i'm asking how to do this

It has to require an username and password which are both located in the database. (eg. user:admin, pass:root)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Controller action that checks the credentials in the request, and [validates the user without logging him in](http://laravel.com/docs/security).

For example, in your **routes.php** file:

```
Route::controller('api', 'ApiController');
```

**Your controller** (**note**: I've used `anyMyMethod()` so that the method is available via GET and POST.. to accept just GET it would be `getMyMethod()`):

```
class ApiController extends BaseController {

    public function anyMyMethod()
    {
        $user = array(
            'username' => Input::get('user', false),
            'password' => Input::get('pass', false)
            );

        if (Auth::validate($user))
        {
            // user is valid.. do things!
            return "ok";
        }
        else
        {
            // user is not valid.. return an auth error.
            return "fail";
        }
    }
}
```

Now your API is available though the URL: your-domain.com/api/my-method, and you can test it with cURL:

```
curl -d "user=admin&pass=root" your-domain.com/api/my-method
```

and there you have it, an API method!